# how to combine Android phone's wifi hotspot and USB tethering so that they are in same network?

Tags: windows, wifi-hotspot, usb-tethering

I want to transfer files from one Windows 10 computer to the another, for this I usually use Ethernet crossover cable but its transfer speed is (100/100 Mbps)
[image]

I have a 5Ghz wifi adapter in only one of my PCs and 5Ghz wifi hotspot in my Android 10 phone which gives speeds upto (433/433 Mbps) also when I use USB tethering from Android Phone it gives speed upto (425/425 Mbps)

So, What I'm trying to accomplish here is to connect one of the PCs to 5Ghz wifi (Remember I have only 1 adapter of 5Ghz) network  and another to USB tethering network using the same phone so that they are both in the same network and hence I may transfer files.

But the problem I am facing here is that the Android 10 phone is providing Different networks (IPv4 network addresses are different) for both the Wifi hotspot and the USB tethering in both the PCs.

Wifi Network Details:[image]

USB tethering network details:[image]

So what can I do? so that both the computers are in same networks using such connections from Android 10 phone.

Comment: Don't use Windows PCs as the end points to make file transfer operations. Instead, use Android as the end point for both networks (because it can access both networks at the same time). What you can do is: 1) download a file manager app with network filesystem support (such as FTP, WebDAV, SFTP, etc.). 2) Setup an FTP or a SSH server or a WebDAV on both your PCs. 3) Connect both PCs to hotspot and tethering respectively. 4) Configure your file manager app to access both the PCs. Than use the same file manager to transfer/copy files from one PC to another.

Comment: If your device is rooted and uses `dnsmasq` as DHCP server, then it's possible: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214072/218526

Comment: @Firelord how about merging these or marking duplicates: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/241852, https://android.stackexchange.com/q/236678, https://android.stackexchange.com/q/226520, https://android.stackexchange.com/q/219973, https://android.stackexchange.com/q/119147, https://android.stackexchange.com/q/116447, https://android.stackexchange.com/q/106625, https://android.stackexchange.com/q/26934 and this one?

Comment: @IrfanLatif sorry, I'm busy for a couple of days so can't spend much time here. I will ask other mods to see if they can look into it.

Comment: Here's another https://android.stackexchange.com/q/174642